# Combining these three queries in one line in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have these Postgres SQL, that is in between some `while` loop:

```
while (.......) {
...  
$runStatement = 'update products set abc = "'.data[0].'" where abc = "'.data[1].'";';
...
}

while (.......) {
...  
$runStatement = 'update products set xyz = "'.data[0].'" where xyz = "'.data[1].'";';
...
}

while (.......) {
...  
$runStatement = 'update extra_products set abc = "'.data[0].'" where abc = "'.data[1].'";';
...
}
```

where each loop, `data` is actually read from the same array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the statements with semicolons between them and run them in one call to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops. You can do a JOIN in your update, the first table being for instance products, and the second table is a long list of VALUES (old,new),(old,new), etc. This allows to update many rows in one command and is much faster.